# A Problem in Parsing CNAME with Libpcap: some CNAMEs seems missing TLD

Tags: c++, dns, cname, libpcap

I am writing a DNS reply parser with libpcap and find that some CNAMEs' TLDs seem to be missing from the corresponding DNS packet payload. One example is shown in an example packet's wireshark dissection[image: wireshark output] where wireshark shows the actual CNAME is

```
prd-push-access-net5-175542503.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

but I can only find

```
prd-push-access-net5-175542503.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws
```

(i.e. no ".com") in the corresponding part of payload. I wonder how could one (and how did wireshark) parse the full CNAME (with ".com") out of this payload?

(Also this CNAME seems malformed since per RFC1035, a QNAME in question section should "terminates with the zero length octet for the null label of the root" and I guess the same applies for CNAME?)

Comment: How big is the packet?  Is it all shown in the image?  There are several parts to the URL highlighted, consecutively stored as several strings preceded by a length byte with no zero terminator byte.  Maybe the "com" part is elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS packets use name compression, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035 section 4.1.4

In many places (where names appear), each label can be represented by a pointer to a former place in the packet where it appears already, instead of the string.

In your example, we can clearly see `com` in `myfoscam.com` earlier in the packet.

So with the content (using only the end because it is tedious to extract data from an image, you should have copied things as text) `03656c6209616d617a6f6e617773c019c02e00` we have to analyze it like this:

- `03`:  the following is a string of length 3
- `656c62`: this is the string `elb`, lenght 3 as advertised
- `09`: the following is a string of length 9
- `616d617a6f6e617773`: this is the string `amazonaws`
- `c0` : this has the first two bits as 1 (since it is value 192, so more or equal to 128+64), which means it is a part of a two bytes pointer. Hence `c019` is a pointer here at offset 25 in decimal (`19` in hexadecimal) into the packet.

So if you start from the whole packet, and switch to offset 25, you should find the sequence `03636f6d` which is `com` (with the prefix of a length of 3).

Or maybe something else, because you have another pointer after in fact: `c02e`, so this is for offset 46 in the message. Or that part is for something else completely, it really depends on what is pointed by previous pointer, if it finishes with a null label or not (if it is `03636f6d00` at offset 25 or not). See example in the RFC (and/or provide all the packet content as text in your question)

Then it ends with `00` the null label, which means the root (the hidden `.` at the end of any name).

Comment: I see. I didn't realize name compression could be applied to part of the domain name. Thank you Patrick! Life saver! (I confimed offset 25 from the start of the DNS message,  i.e., the first octet of the ID field in the DNS header,  is ".com")